# ler arquivo json e depois listar os nomes com reactJS

Tags: javascript, react, promises

eu estou criando um site com react e tenho que ler um arquivo json(isso é indispensável), mas me deparei com um problema, quando mando executar um map para criar uma lista com os nomes, não estou conseguindo, acredito que seja por quê a variável é uma promise, enfim, este é meu código:

lendo o arquivo data.json e salvando no estado global

```
    fetch('./data.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => setDataGlobal(res.stores))
  }
  , []);
```

depois eu pego o valor retornado e faço o map

```
<ul>
  { dataGlobal.map(async (el) => <li>{ el.name }</li>) }
</ul>
```

agradeço por qualquer ajuda ou dica

Comment: `map(async` não tem isso não.

Answer (score -1):

Remova o `async` do seu `map` e garanta que o estado inicial do seu `dataGlobal` é um array vazio.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).